# Function on a star domain has a primitive

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $U \subset \Bbb C$ be a star domain and $f:U \to \Bbb C$ continuous, s.t.
$$\int_{\partial \bigtriangleup}f(z)dz=0$$
for all triangles $\bigtriangleup$ which are in $U$. It is to be shown that $f$ has a primitive.

Let $z_0 \in U$ be a center of the star domain, so for $z \in U$ the segment between $z_0$ and $z$ is in $U$. We denote the segment between $z_0$ and $z$ with $[z_0,z]$. Let
$$F(z):=\int_{[z_0,z]}f(w)dw$$
Now $U$ is open and so it exists $r>0$ s.t. $B(z,r) \subset U$. If we take $\vert u \vert <r$, then the segment $[z,z+u]$ lies in $U$. Because the integral over a triangle is $0$ it follows for the triangle $[z_0,z,z+u]$ that
$$F(z+u)-F(z)=\int_{[z,z+u]}f(w)dw.$$
But now how can I conclude the proof? I should show that
$$\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{F(z+u)-F(z)}{u}=f(z)$$
But I got stuck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the parametrization $[0, 1] \ni t \mapsto z +tu$ of the segment $[z, z+u]$ we get
$$
F(z+u)-F(z)= u  \int_0^1 f(z +t u) \, dt 
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{F(z+u)-F(z)}{u}  - f(z) = \int_0^1 \bigl(f(z +t u) -f(z) \bigr) \, dt \, .
$$
$f$ is continuous at $z$, so given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(w) - f(z)| < \epsilon $ if $|w-z| < \delta$. It follows that if $|u| < \delta$ then
$$
\left|\frac{F(z+u)-F(z)}{u}  - f(z) \right| \le \int_0^1 \underbrace{|f(z +t u) -f(z) |}_{< \epsilon} \, dt < \epsilon
$$
and that proves the desired limit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So we can swap the integral and the limes on the integral on the right side and conclude that for $u\to 0$ it tends to zero?

Comment: @FrederickManfred: You could, but it is not necessary. $|f(z+tu) - f(z)|$ is small for sufficiently small $u$ and *all* $t \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: Yes, but we don't use there the continuity or I missed something?

Comment: @FrederickManfred: The continuity of $f$ is used to make that expression small. I have extended the answer with more details.

Comment: Thank you, now everything is clear!!